# Images Not Appearing in WatchKit App

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have a small WatchKit app with six images on the main interface. **When I run the app in my simulator on my machine, the images appear and everything works.**

I submitted the app for review and the review was rejected with a screenshot of the app that had no images. I can only guess that the images aren't making it into the archive.

Details:
* I'm working in Xcode 6.3.

- "Target Membership" is set for all images to: my app, Extension, and WatchKit App
- The images are in the "Supporting Files" directory of the WatchKit App.
- I didn't add anything to "Images.xcassets"
- All app icons display correctly FWIW

Comment: Try building it on another person's computer and see if the error persists.

Comment: I pulled out my old laptop, upgraded to Yosemite, installed Xcode 6.3.1, and ran the app. The images appear fine.

Comment: FWIW, I have this same problem! My app was approved, but they overlooked the one missing image!

Comment: I re-archived the project and submitted a new build and the new build was approved. Sounds like a bug in the review process.

Comment: When you say `The images appear fine.` you mean on the actual device?

Comment: I meant they appear fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your images are on the Watch bundle and not on the main app bundle.

As far as I know, you have to set the images that will be displayed on the watch on an `Images.xcassets` inside the Watch App. Not the Main App nor the Extension.

I have two `Images.xcassets`one for main app and one for watch app.